# Acessar arquivos fora da pasta raiz do projeto (Desenvolvimento Web)

Tags: php, html, nginx, docker

Estou trabalhando em um sistema Web utilizando o Docker com Nginx. E não estou conseguindo acessar os arquivos que não estejam na pasta raiz do projeto, se possível gostaria de entender o que está acontecendo e como posso solucionar.

Segue abaixo o código do docker-compose.yml

```
 nginx:
   image: tutum/nginx
   ports:
     - "80:80"
   links:
     - phpfpm
   volumes:
     - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
     - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
     - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
     - ./logs/nginx-acess.log:/var/log/nginx/acess.log

phpfpm:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html

mysql:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8183:80
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=admin
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

Segue abaixo o default do NGINX:

```
server {
listen 80;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;

server_name "IP_LOCAL";

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

Imagem de como está estruturado o projeto com os apontamentos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída no localhost
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código index.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset ="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="config/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="config/css/login.css">

</head>

<body>  
    <div class="login-form col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1  col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3  col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <header>
            <h1><img class="img-responsive" src="img/app-mini.png"></h1>
            <h2 class="text-center"> Entre com o seu <b>usuário</b> e <b>senha</b> </h2>
        </header>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="usuário" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
            <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" name="Lembrar">Esquecer a Senha</label>              
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"> Entrar</button>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src= "config/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="config/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: "*- não estou conseguindo acessar os arquivos.*" Quais arquivos? Onde está "invocando-os"? Poste seu código em forma de texto: [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas).

Comment: LipESprY -de folga-, Código adicionado.

Answer (score 1):

- Quando você invoca algum arquivo **no servidor**, você pode "subir" o nível do diretório com `../` sem estar limitado ao diretório raiz do site.
- Quando você invoca algum arquivo **no cliente** (navegador), você fica limitado ao diretório raiz e seus sub diretórios.

Veja no seu `index.php` estas linhas:

```
...
<link rel= "stylesheet" href="config/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel= "stylesheet" href="config/css/login.css">
...
<script src= "config/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="config/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
```

Repare na estrutura dos diretórios **onde está o `index.php`**:

[image: Níveis]

**No cliente**, você pode invocar os arquivos **à partir da raiz** adicionando uma `/` no início do caminho. Lembre-se que a raiz é o diretório onde está o `index.php`, ou seja: `http://meusite.com.br/index.php`.

**No servidor, com o PHP**, você pode acessar qualquer pasta. Desde que o usuário que está rodando o Apache tenha tal permissão. Aí a `/` representa o diretório raiz do seu servidor, quando se trata de Linux.

O ideal é você ver onde está o arquivo invocador e, a cada diretório que você voltar, adicionar `../` no caminho.

Um simples exemplo: digamos que você quer o conteúdo do arquivo `default` que está na pasta `nginx` **à partir do `index.php` que está na pasta `app`**:

```
<?php
    $arquivo = file_get_contents('../nginx/default');
?>
```

- Estou na pasta `app` (chamando à partir do `index.php`);
- Voltei uma pasta: `../`;
- Entrei na pasta `nginx/`;
- Indiquei o arquivo `default`;

Comment: entendo porém ainda não consigo trazer o bootstrap e nem acessar uma própria imagem trazendo para raiz em uma pagina de teste.

Comment: @Jack Já tentou acessar esses arquivos diretamente, pelo navegador?! Exemplo: `http://localhost/config/js/bootstrap.min.js`. Já conferiu se o apache tem permissão de leitura nesses arquivos que vc tá tentando acessar? Já verificou o console do navegador?